# Where inside module to save single for of single field?

Tags: module, database

I need to save a date of last imported data. This is one single row of single field. Is there any other way or do I need only for this single row and field create new table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best place to do it is to use Magento config. Something like this:

```
Mage::getModel('core/config')->saveConfig('your_module/your_group/your_value', $value);
```

Then you can get it anywhere in your code like this:

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('your_module/your_group/your_value');
```

Comment: Hi Tim, can u please explain about "The best place to do it is to use Magento config"... When can we use this? and how it is useful?...sorry, if my questions feels like a silly question but I want to knw...Thanks

Comment: I also thought about that, I just wasn't sure if this is the right location because this is not config. MagentoBoy in module system.xml I would put this as field, but set show_in_default,show_in_website,show_in_store to 0 so it will create that field but user won't see it in admin.

Comment: @JohnyFree you don't even have to put it into `system.xml`. The code above will create a config record regardless if it was declared in your module or not.

Comment: @MagentoBoy Magento has a special table called `core_config_data` where it stores all config values.

Comment: @tim.. thanks:) ...means that value can be accessible as that variable is a part of the core config data and can be accessible anywhere...

Comment: @MagentoBoy not as a variable. the second code sample in my answer shows how it can be accessed.

Comment: @Tim .. got it ..it will be saved in database and we can retrieve it .. according to the code.. :) ... thanks for correcting me.

Comment: And one more thing Tim .. that is.. JohnyFree want to save the date field while exporting the data.. and everytime when he will export the data it will be saved in config file.. so is it good to save in config file ...???

Comment: @MagentoBoy it's not saved in a file but a database table

Comment: Yes sorry, i meant to say in database only... :)

Answer (score 2):

**Tim's answer is correct** and it's what I would reach for 99% of the time.

But then there's always that one time where storing it in the Magento config feels 'wrong' somehow especially if there were some other entity that needed to access this date to perform some action.

In that case you can store the information in a separate table `import_queue` with a list of jobs:

```
+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
| entity_id |     imported_at     |    completed_at     | rows_imported |
+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
|         1 | 2011-01-01 00:00:00 | 2011-01-01 04:39:59 |       4443333 |
+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
```

You can derive a wealth of information from a table like this -- very handy if your jobs are running outside of Magento or via cron and you don't have to worry about 3rd party jobs futzing with Magento's configuration table.

Of course if you're always running import jobs and you're always logging when they happen you may want to have some other form of data to backtrace - such as writing to a log file or even the system log. If running from Cron you can always check the cron log execution and if you're really savvy have it output some really useful information for future use.

If you really want to torture yourself (or your intern) you can generate an email with import summaries and force (your intern) to sort through it all later when you need to get some statisics from this vital data.

In summary, there are an endless number of methods to keeping a log of **when** an import runs - but **which method is best** really depends on h**ow and when you will use it** in the future.